# iOS - Default Activity loader like "please wait"

Tags: ios

I want to add a loader in uiview while calling an API or any background method. is there any default on it? or i have create custom loader.

Comment: No, creating a custom one would be a sensible approach.

Comment: yes i found the right one.

Comment: Btw, such [an article](http://www.iosinsight.com/uiactivityindicatorview-with-custom-text-in-swift/) might be useful to be checked in your case...

Comment: i need onjective C code. but thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
-(void)loaderType1 :(UIView *)View
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                             initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=View.center;
    activityView.color=(UIColor*)[UIColor blackColor]; //change color
    activityView.tag=10;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    //this is for freeze UI when loader appears
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];      
    //this is for stop the previous action
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [View addSubview:activityView];
    [View bringSubviewToFront:activityView];
}
```

**now call this anywhere like -**

```
[self loaderType1: self.view];
```

**To remove loader:**

```
 if ([self.view viewWithTag:10])
 {
   [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is default activityIndicator in iOS. You can add like that.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            activity.center = view.center

            // Customization
            activityIndicator.color                      = UIColor.blue
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray

            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        }
    }
```

to start animating where you want:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

to stop animating where you want:

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

to remove from view:

```
activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property UIActivityIndicatorView * spinner;
_spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[self.view addSubview:_spinner];
[_spinner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
_spinner.center = self.view.center;
_spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
[_spinner setColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

//Now start spinner where you want
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_spinner];
[_spinner startAnimating];
//Stop spinner
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_spinner stopAnimating];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can write/paste the below code in your base uiviewcontroller and call the respective/current viewcontroller whenever we need to show/hide loading bar.

Kindly note we can play/optimize with the blocker view with UILabel like loading or custom text as well.

```
-(void)makeScreenBusy {
if(!self.spinner){
    [self createSpinner];
}
[self.view addSubview:self.blockerView];
[self.blockerView setAlpha:0];
self.spinner.center = self.blockerView.center;
[UIView animateWithDuration:kMinimumAnimationDuration animations:^{
    [self.blockerView setAlpha:0.5];
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
}];
```

}

```
-(void)makeScreenAvailable {
[UIView animateWithDuration:kMinimumAnimationDuration animations:^{
    [self.blockerView setAlpha:0];
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.blockerView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

}

```
-(void)createSpinner {
[self.blockerView setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.blockerView setAlpha:0.5];

self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
[self.spinner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[self.blockerView addSubview:self.spinner];
```

}